# Error When Update Eclipse with Grandle

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

My Eclipse :
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857
(Installed with Android ADT)

JDK 7
JRE 7

i recently learn Libgdx become grandle project, so it says to import project created by libgdx jar into Eclipse using Import->Grandle->....
But i cannot find it in "import".

After searching, it must added additionally plugin into eclipse

I try to update my Eclipse with Grandle by "install new software" and add url such as :

```
http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/gradle/nightly (latest development snapshot)
http://dist.springsource.com/milestone/TOOLS/gradle (latest milestone build)
http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle (latest release)
```

But it said error like :

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core,3.6.2.201410090835-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\LUTHFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6188792910440798483.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\LUTHFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6188792910440798483.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature,3.6.2.201410090835-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\LUTHFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9055408208958627131.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\LUTHFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9055408208958627131.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.toolingapi,3.6.2.201410090835-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\LUTHFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile158162502031506472.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\LUTHFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile158162502031506472.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui,3.6.2.201410090835-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\LUTHFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8390443836635093074.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\LUTHFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8390443836635093074.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.taskview,3.6.2.201410090835-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\LUTHFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4151621413709401624.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\LUTHFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4151621413709401624.jar
```

I search more link and get :
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/243191/
that says i must add following lane to my eclipse.ini

```
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
```

but looks like no result at all..

i also follow this :
https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/
but cannot and still displayed error above.

another link : 
http://estiloasertivo.blogspot.com/2013/03/tutorial-howto-install-and-configure.html
still not work.

i dont know what should i do anymore.
please help me or point me to fix those problems..

Thank you

Sorry if little messy in my explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't update Eclipse to grandle, Grandle is an separate compilation kit an this feature is added in Android Studio. So, better download Android Studio instead of updating eclipse

Comment: but i cannot run desktop application like i do with eclipse (libgdx provide desktop and android project), any idea to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to open a command line from your main project and do a 'gradlew eclipse'. Once that runs, you should be able to import it in Eclipse as a normal existing project since Gradle will have generated the Eclipse-related project files that are needed for Eclipse to recognize and build a project.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse recommended **(4.4) 3.6.2.RELEASE** for gradle plugin. Check [this](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44#.VECYV_mSx1E). you just need to drag install button from here to your eclipse and it will start downloading and installing.

Comment: I already try this. same as other comment below that page, cannot.